# Unit testing angularjs with karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I've set up karma to run angular tests, but when i try and get a factory I've defined with the angular.injector().get("EventProcessor") it says its not found.

my factory looks like this:

```
console.log "Loaded"

TTApp.factory "EventProcessor", ($rootScope, $injector) ->
  console.log "Inside" # this is never seen in the log...
  class EventProcessor
    ...
```

my root app looks like this:

```
window.TTApp = angular.module("TTApp", [
  "ui.layout",
  "ui.bootstrap",
  "templates"
])

TTApp.run ->
  ...
```

my test looks like this:

```
describe "EventProcessor", ->
  beforeEach(module("TTApp"))

  it "is there", ->   
    subject = angular.injector().get("EventProcessor")
    expect(subject).not.toBeNull()
```

Exact error is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: EventProcessorProvider <- EventProcessor
```

Anyone have any insight in to what I'm doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I found I need to use

```
angular.injector(["ngMock", "ng", "TTApp"]).get so it knows where to look.
```

Thanks google..